# PHP while loop first button is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have created a while loop for the data fetched from the database. I have added a button to each loop. when the user clicks on the button, it should open a new tab and since I am using the form method="GET" the data is getting passed to the new tab window.
This is not working only for the first loop button, whereas it is working fine for all other buttons created by the loop. Can someone help? The code is as below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        $row = 1;
        $number = 1;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<tr>';
        $invoiceNumber = $row["invoiceNumber"]`enter code here`;
        echo ' <td align="center" style="text-align:center">' . $invoiceNumber . '</td>';
        echo ' <td align="right">' . $row["invoiceDate"] . '</td>';
        echo ' <td align="right">' . $row["accountName"] . '</td>';
        $beginTime = $row["beginTime"];
        $beginTime = date("D, j M Y", strtotime($beginTime));
        echo ' <td align="right">' . $beginTime . '</td>';
        $endTime = $row["endTime"];
        $endTime = date("D, j M Y", strtotime($endTime));
        echo ' <td align="right">' . $endTime . '</td>';
        echo ' <td align="center"style="text-align:center"><form method = "GET" action= "invoice.php" name="'.$number.'"><button name= "invoice" value='.$invoiceNumber.'></form>View</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $number = $number + 1;

    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more about your problem?

Comment: i guess you should start index with 0 instead of 1. pls check and let me know

Comment: your HTML nesting is kind of weird, <form><button></form></button> it should be <form><button></button></form>

Comment: I tried the same, but no luck...so I tried the above...still not working.

Comment: Srinivas - I have used index as 0 inititally, then while searching over the net, i found someone stating i should start from 1, so I have made the change

Answer (score 1):

Saw that the form closing tag `</form>` is inside the `<button>` tag, would you try to change it to:

```html
<td align="center"style="text-align:center">
    <form method = "GET" action= "invoice.php" name="'.$number.'">
        <button name= "invoice" value='.$invoiceNumber.'>View</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

See if it helps..

Comment: I tried the same, but still no luck....it just wont open a new tab for the first loop....for the rest of loops, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code and removed the form tag. It works **perfectly** for all buttons now including the first button in while loop. Code is as below :

```
echo ' <td align="center"style="text-align:center"><button id="invoice" name= "invoice[]" value='.$invoiceNumber.'>View</button></td>';


<?php

if ($_POST['invoice']) {

$name = $_POST['invoice'];
$array = $name[0];
//echo $array;
echo '<script>window.open("invoice.php?'.$array.'","_blank")</script>';
}
?>
```